# Reading Informix-SE audit trail log tables

Tags: informix

INFORMIX-SQL 7.32 (SE):

I've created an audit trail "a_trx" for my transaction table to know who/when has added or updated rows in this table, with a snapshot of the rows contents. According to documentation, an audit table is created with the same schema of the table being audited, plus the following audit info header columns pre-fixed:

```
table a_trx

a_type        char(2)    {record type: aa = added, dd =deleted,
                          rr = before update image, ww = after update image.}
a_time        integer    {internal time value.}
a_process_id  smallint   {Process ID that changed record.}
a_usr_id      smallint   {User ID that changed record.}
a_rowid       integer    {Original rowid.}
[...]                    {Same columns as table being audited.}
```

So then I proceeded to generate a default perform screen for a_trx, but could not locate a_trx for my table selection. I aborted and ls'd the .dbs directory and did not see a_trx.dat or a_trx.idx, but found a_trx, which appears to be in .dat format, according to
my disk editor utility. Is there any other method for accessing this .dat clone or do I have to trick the engine by renaming it to a_trx.dat, create an .idx companion for it, tweak SYSTABLES, SYSCOLUMNS, etc. to be able to access this audit table like any other table?.. and what is the internal time value of a_time, number of seconds since 12/31/1899?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audit logs are not C-ISAM files; they are plain log files.  IIRC, they are created with '.aud' as a suffix.  If you get to choose the suffix, then you would create it with a '.dat' suffix, making sure the name does not conflict with any table name.

You should be able to access them as if they were a table, but you would have to create a table (data file) and the index file to match the augmented schema, and then arrange for the '.aud' file to refer to the same location as the '.dat' file - presumably via a link or possibly a symbolic link.  You can specify where the table is stored in the CREATE TABLE statement in SE.

The time is a Unix time stamp - the number of seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

Comment: Would the .dat clone table owner be informix?.. How come one has to go through all these hoops to read an audit table when there should've been a cleaner way to read audit tables to begin with?

Comment: @Frank: the owner could be anyone.  Audit trails were designed to be used with C-ISAM files - not with SE tables.  SE happens to make them available to you.  Besides, you need to audit the audit-trail table, which requires an audit trail of the audit trail... :D

Comment: An of the subject question to part of your above comment: Besides specifying where to create the table with the IN "..."; can I specify EXTENTS or is that only in IDS?

Comment: @Frank: extents are a concept in IDS only - not SE.  You can specify the file name where the file(s) will be stored in SE; you can specify the dbspace(s) where the data will be stored in IDS.